# Expected expression before ‘list’ [C]

Tags: c, terminal, linked-list

This is a short version of my original program but the error output is the same.
I have 3 file:

`list.h` `list.c` and `main.c`

In the `main.c` file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    list *head = NULL;
    int b;

    printf("Type int: \n");

    while(b != 0){
        scanf("%d", &b);
        add(b);
    }

    print_list(list *head);
}
```

And when I compile:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:13: error: expected expression before ‘list’
  print_list(list *t);
             ^~~~
```

The 'list' type is already declared in `list.h` by:

```
typedef struct lis{
    int item;
    struct lis *next;
}list;
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: `print_list(list *head);` should be `print_list(head);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with the codes, first one already mentioned in the comments, you should call `print()` as

```
print_list(head);
```

instead of

```
print_list(list *head);
```

Secondly, I am assuming that `add()` function is for adding new nodes into list with the field `item` being provided as `b`. But I don't see `head` is being updated or passed from `main()` function to any other function which makes your `head` as `NULL` all the time, if true. I guess you should call `add()` like below

```
list *head = NULL; /* since its declared locally, you should pass to function like add() so that it can get updated */
while(b != 0){
    scanf("%d", &b);
    add(&head,b); /* calling add() function */
}
print(head);/* after head being updated through add() function, call the print() fun */
```

And define the `add()` function like

```
void add(list **ptr,int num) {
   /* logic for creating the list */
   list *new = malloc(sizeof(list));/* everytime create new node */

   new->item = num;/* fill the item field */
   new->next = *ptr; /* update the new->next */
   (*ptr) = new;/* update the head, this is important */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm!

Comment: your welcome @Gekobix

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing a pointer by dereference-ing them then you have to make sure you have declared it separately and it is pointing to some memory (else you'll receive warning). In your case it is not happening, you have declared a pointer and passed it at the same time. Here is an example to pass dereferenced pointer:

```
 void fun(int i)
 {                      //BLANK FUNCTION 
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     int i=9,*j;
     i=&j;

     fun(*i);          //PASSING DEREFERENCED POINTER
     return 0;
 }
```

It would be better in your case to create a pointer to the first node of linked list and then pass it without dereferencing it i.e.

```
  print_list(head);
```